# Flexbox: How to make box shrink to size of content like float or inline-block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What is the tag (if one exists) that instructs a flex container to shrink to the size of it's internal content?  `Float` and `inline-block` snap down automatically.  I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a single discussion about this easy concept.

Comment: `display: inline-flex;`

Comment: @MichaelCoker  That was it!  Worked perfect.  I could not find that tag to save my life.

Comment: @DR01D this is a good reference https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Michael_B `display: inline-flex` worked perfect.  I'm just trying to replicate the way `float` and `inline-block` snap down to the size of their content instead of taking up 100% of the available width.

Comment: @DR01D yeah I get it, I gave you the link because they cover `display: inline-flex;` and every other flexbox property in it. It's worth bookmarking and using it as a reference.

Comment: @DR01D not that you should, but you can always float a flex container, too.